# Убрать грид-сетку, если контета нет

Tags: html, css

Нужно скрыть сетку, если карточки не наполнены
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
введите сюда код
```

Comment: Повесьте класс, если "карточки не наполнены" и укажите в css для него спрятать сетку

Comment: @Inventor: что значит "Повесьте...", "... укажите..."? Под картинкой явно же написано - `введите сюда код` :-)

Comment: Так это вам на фриланс биржу, тут за вас код никто писать не будет